# Can I Conditionally add a function to my class?

Tags: php, class

In the framework question 2 answers, themes are an extension of a base theme `qa_html_theme_base`. In this example I extend the html-function that outputs html.

```
class qa_html_theme extends qa_html_theme_base
    {
        function html(){
           //Theme goes here   
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to quickly turn on and off my theme for testing purposes. Is it possible to conditionally extend a class, I tried

```
class qa_html_theme extends qa_html_theme_base
    {
        if($debug){
            function html(){}
        }
    }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: If `html` function is override, you can call [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) `html` method E.g : `if(!$debug){ parent::html(); return;}`

Comment: Do you search for a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)? [Here](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) you find a example implementation in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is possible, this syntax inside a class declaration wouldn't be correct. And if it was, I'm not sure I would recommend it.

But if your function is overriding one of the extended class functions, you could do the following :

```
class qa_html_theme extends qa_html_theme_base
{
    function html(){
        global $debug; // added to maintain a correct syntax, but you could as well use $this->debug below, if the value comes from a class property.
        if( $debug ){
            // your debug code here
        }
        else {
            parent::html();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** `$debug` isn't in the local scope of `html()` - either `global` it, make it a class property, or pass it into the function as an argument.

Comment: this won't work as it overrides the default html-class.

Comment: @hd: I didn't know where this $debug variable came from on the example... so I leave it the way it was on the question ^^. But you're right, it should be a global variable or a class property.

Comment: @Himmators: What's the "default html-class" you're talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do what you're suggesting (and it's clunky at best) is to conditionally include the class file. So create two class files. We'll call the first `theme_html.php` and it includes your `html()` function. The second would be `theme_no_html.php` and it does NOT have your `html()` function. This is clunky because you'll have two files to maintain.

Then we do

```
if($debug) {
     include('theme_html.php');
} else {
     include('theme_no_html.php');
}
$class = new qa_html_theme();
```

Answer (score 0):

if my mind is right,

```
class qa_html_theme extends qa_html_theme_base
{
    protected $debug = 1; // or const DEBUG = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if($this->debug){
            $this->html();
        }else{
          // do anything you want
        }
    }

    protected function html(){
       //Theme goes here   
    }
}
```